# Using preg_replace on url variables

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have some very long URL variables. Here is one example.

```
http://localhost/index.php?image=XYZ_1555025022.jpg&mppdf=yes&pdfname=Printer&deskew=yes&autocrop=yes&print=no&mode=color&printscalewidth100=&printscaleheight100=&rand=56039
```

Ultimately it would be nice if I could find a way to use `preg_replace` to simply change one variable even if in the middle of the string for instance in the string above change `print=no` to `'print=yes` for example.

I will however settle for a `preg_replace` pattern match that allows me to delete `?image=XYZ_1555025022.jpg`. as this is a variable the name could be anything. It will always have "`?image"` " at the start and end with "`&`"

I think one of the problems I have run into is that `preg_match` seems to have issues on strings with "=" contained in them .

I am completely lost here in this and all those characters make may head spin. Maybe someone can give some guidance please?

Comment: if you just want to replace exact string why not use str_replace?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo of how you can do some of things you want using [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [`parse_str`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php):

```
$url = 'http://localhost/index.php?image=XYZ_1555025022.jpg&mppdf=yes&pdfname=Printer&deskew=yes&autocrop=yes&print=no&mode=color&printscalewidth100=&printscaleheight100=&rand=56039';
// split on first ?
list($path, $query_string) = explode('?', $url, 2);
// parse the query string
parse_str($query_string, $params);
// delete image param
unset($params['image']);
// change the print param
$params['print'] = 'yes';
// rebuild the query
$query_string = http_build_query($params);
// reassemble the URL
$url = $path . '?' . $query_string;
echo $url;
```

Output:

```
http://localhost/index.php?mppdf=yes&pdfname=Printer&deskew=yes&autocrop=yes&print=yes&mode=color&printscalewidth100=&printscaleheight100=&rand=56039
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/F74oW)

Comment: @NullPoiиteя it couldn't (it would be URL encoded). But how can you write a `str_replace` which will work for any filename between `image=` and `&`?

Comment: agreed, image can have `=` , my bad, anyway only member for 1year and 40k nice work sir

Comment: @NullPoiиteя thanks - I have to confess to have become a bit addicted to that little green pop-up :-)

Comment: @Nick absolutely AMAZING . I can not tell you how tired I was getting of tracking these URL variables and what applies where and typing '&this='.$that. WHat a relief. I looked for an answer like this a year ago to no avail but nw back to the same code and you made it so much easiier. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_replace()` or `preg_replace()` to get your job done, but `parse_url()` with `parse_str()` will give you more controls to modify any parameters easily by array index. Finally use [http_build_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to make your final url after modification.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://localhost/index.php?image=XYZ_1555025022.jpg&mppdf=yes&pdfname=Printer&deskew=yes&autocrop=yes&print=no&mode=color&printscalewidth100=&printscaleheight100=&rand=56039';
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
echo "BEFORE".PHP_EOL;
print_r($query);
$query['print'] = 'yes';
echo "AFTER".PHP_EOL;
print_r($query);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/npGij